# Pioneer3-Navigation-tf-/odom /map problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have some problems with a rebuild pioneer3-dx. The rebuild is with a construction(nearby 4kg weight and a Sick LMS 200). Right now I use the navigation stack ( AMCL and the Move_Base) and the p2os-stack(dashboard, motor, driver, joystick). While the robot runs with this configuration, the odom frame drifts farther and farther from the map-frame(the odom rotates around the base_link) see [Scheme](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/4978873/overview-pdf-605k?da=y). After 3 rotations it lose its orientation of the map.
The problem is when I send the target vectors to [move_base_client](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals)  direct, the zero coordinates change from map(as start point) to odom. At this situation the starting point is now at a new position in the wall. I tried to manipulate the values from navfn and amcl(odom-values) to compress the failure without success. Has anyone knowledge about this problems??  Thanks in anticipate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47588/pioneer3-navigation-tf-/odom-/map-problem/) by [keron](https://answers.ros.org/users/3531/keron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-06**:
What do you men with "the zero coordinates change from map to odom"?

**Comment by [keron](https://answers.ros.org/users/3531/keron/) on 2012-11-06**:
I mean the origin frame, if I start the robot. This pose is at the frame /map. Normally, during the robot is active /odom should have always the same position nearby the /map. But if I use a joystick or the move_base_client ,the frame /odom drift away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a problem, but the correct behaviour. The /odom frame naturally has drift and thus will not coincide with /map when running localization. If you want to address coordinates in a globally consistent frame, use /map, not /odom.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0